# R remove duplicated values based on a column and replace other column values with the mean of duplicated rows

Tags: r, duplicates, environment-variables, geospatial, mean

I'm working with a data.frame which has 6 environmental variables of interest which are georeferenced by location.  The problem I have is that some of the locations are duplicated but all the environmental variables are unique measurements.

Unfortunately, the modelling I want to do with these data will not work if there are duplicate locations. But I do not wish to arbitrarily throw away data by keeping only one duplicated row.

So, I'm looking for a method of taking the means for each of the 6 variables for each set of duplicates and then ascribing that mean to each variable and the location thereby preserving the information from the multiple measurements.

I've attempted this in several ways but I can't quite seem to get it right!

The data I'm working with can be downloaded here:
(https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xnwp3zz5abnilyo/AABRVJZ0kTmWk0T9Fcp4-bVSa?dl=0/)

This is how I've attempted this :

```
    library(rgdal)
    library(sp)
    library(maptools)

 #load data 

hs1<- readOGR (".", "Hollicombe_S1_L1-5_A1.2")

#remove columns we're not interested in

hs1<- subset(hs1, select = -c(1:16, 23:24)
```

So I start with hs1 - a SPDF with 552 obs and 6 variables...

```
    #check for duplicate location (present if lengths differ)
length(hs1@coords) 
[1] 1104  
length(unique(hs1@coords))
[1] 730
#duplicates confirmed

hs1.d <- hs1[duplicated(hs1@coords),] # creates new SPDF with only duplicated locations (?)
hs1.u <- hs1[!duplicated(hs1@coords),] # creates new SPDF with only unique locations

# coerce duplicated locations SPDF to an ordinary data frame 

hs1.md<- as.data.frame(hs1.d)  

# combine the X&Y into a single "location"
hs1.md <- within(hs1.md,  
  Location <- paste(coords.x1, coords.x2, sep = ",")) 

# aggregate duplicate locations and calculate a mean value for each

means_by_location<-  aggregate (cbind(BioArea,BioVolume,MeanBioHei,MaxBioheig,PerArIn, PerVolIn)~Location,  hs1.md, mean)

#split location back to X&Y

lat_long <- strsplit(means_by_location$Location, ",") 
means_by_location$coords.x1 <- sapply(lat_long, function(x) x[1]) #adds X data back
means_by_location$coords.x2 <- sapply(lat_long, function(x) x[2])#adds Y data back
means_by_location$coords.x1 <- as.numeric (means_by_location$coords.x1) #converts to numeric
means_by_location$coords.x2 <- as.numeric (means_by_location$coords.x2)#converts to numeric

# add spatial information back in to create SPDF

coordinates(means_by_location) = ~coords.x1+coords.x2 # adds the locations 
proj4string(means_by_location) = CRS(proj4string(hs1)) # sets the CRS

# hs1.md as SPDF containing single rows for previously duplicated locations 
# with mean values for each variable

hs1.md <- subset(means_by_location, select = -(1))  

#merge hs1.md and hs1.u to create new SPDF without duplicates

hs1 <- spRbind (hs1.u, hs1.md)
```

So hs1 is now a SPDF with 543 obs (i.e. 9 observations have been removed).

But there still remain duplicate locations and the number of unique locations remains the same :

```
length(hs1@coords) # total number of locations
```

[1] 1086

```
length(unique(hs1@coords)) #number of unique locations
```

[1] 730

I suspect I've incorrectly seperated the unique from the duplicated observations somewhere but my knowledge of R is not sufficient enough me to spot this. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong? Or does anybody know an alternative way I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure they're definitely duplicated points? It might be that `unique()` is comparing their 'uniqueness' to a certain degree of accuracy, making them look like duplicates. If you compare the distances between each point there is a finite distance between points, usually >10m

Comment: Valid point indeed. They may not be precisely duplicated locations because the coordinates have a lot of decimal values and R can only deal correctly with the first n many (16 - I think). I tried to confirm duplication by looking at the distances: `dist <- spDists (hs1@coords)

> length(dist)
[1] 304704
> length(unique(dist))
[1] 201480`

Comment: So it may come down to a choice as what's a duplicate. Another possibility is to use the line data that you dropped (i.e. origin, end) and see if observations intersect each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the answer to this is a bit tricky as what's considered a duplicate is probably dependent on accuracy.

On loading your shapefile I saw each measurement is a line, with an origin, end, and centre. The centre seemed to match the coordinates given in the shapefile.

Assuming the centres are in fact the coordinates, I would use the new `dplyr` verbs in the `sf` package:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("sf")
hs1 = read_sf(".", "Hollicombe_S1_L1-5_A1")

nrow(hs1)
# 552
nrow(hs1[duplicated(hs1$geometry), ])
# 187
```

So we have 552 cases with 187 duplicates (i.e. 365 locations). To obtain the mean for duplicated locations use `group_by()` and `summarise()`:

```
hs1 = hs1 %>% 
  group_by(CentrePos1, CentrePos_) %>% 
  summarise(
    BioArea    = mean(BioArea),
    BioVolume  = mean(BioVolume),
    MeanBioHei = mean(MeanBioHei),
    MaxBioheig = mean(MaxBioheig),
    PerArIn    = mean(PerArIn),
    PerVolIn   = mean(PerVolIn)
  )

hs1
# Simple feature collection with 365 features and 8 fields
# geometry type:  POINT
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: -3.548833 ymin: 50.44483 xmax: -3.542333 ymax: 50.45167
# epsg (SRID):    4326
# proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# A tibble: 365 x 9
# Groups:   CentrePos1 [59]
#    CentrePos1 CentrePos_  BioArea BioVolume MeanBioHei MaxBioheig PerArIn PerVolIn          geometry
#         <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <simple_feature>
#  1  -3.548833   50.44500  0.00000   0.00000      0.192      0.216  -1.000   -1.000 <POINT (-3.54...>
#  2  -3.548833   50.44533  2.27280   0.41470      0.182      0.264  91.410    2.810 <POINT (-3.54...>
#  3  -3.548744   50.44500  6.75470   1.21780      0.180      0.216  74.890    2.210 <POINT (-3.54...>
#  4  -3.548667   50.44506  5.02900   1.14660      0.228      0.228 100.000    3.720 <POINT (-3.54...>
#  5  -3.548667   50.44517  8.24895   1.86555      0.225      0.330  96.550    3.530 <POINT (-3.54...>
#  6  -3.548667   50.44532 10.31200   2.04180      0.198      0.204 100.000    3.210 <POINT (-3.54...>
#  7  -3.548667   50.44536 18.61980   3.67040      0.197      0.276 100.000    3.280 <POINT (-3.54...>
#  8  -3.548667   50.44550  3.31670   0.73700      0.222      0.300  96.150    3.550 <POINT (-3.54...>
#  9  -3.548500   50.44533  6.22370   1.74670      0.269      0.372  81.555    3.470 <POINT (-3.54...>
# 10  -3.548500   50.44550  6.00740   1.00090      0.168      0.234  80.905    2.215 <POINT (-3.54...>
# ... with 355 more rows
```

You can see there are 365 rows, and no duplicates:

```
any(duplicated(hs1$geometry))
# FALSE
```

The new columns have the mean values based on the grouping we performed earlier. If the observation location was unique its original value was returned (well, it's original value divided by 1 I suppose).

I should point out that `sf` is replacing `sp`, `rgdal`, and `rgeos` in `R`, but if you do want to continue using those packages you can convert your `sf` object into `spatialPointsDataFrame` with `as_Spatial()`:

```
hs1_data = st_set_geometry(hs1, NULL)
hs1 = as_Spatial(hs1$geometry)
hs1 = SpatialPointsDataFrame(hs1, hs1_data)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks Phil - that was very keen-eyed of you to notice something useful in the information I was dropping!  The centre position is indeed the same of the coordinates I am using so I think this works. Here is a better way of checking by distance than my earlier comment : `> dist <- zerodist(hs1, 0, unique.ID = TRUE)
> length (dist)
[1] 552
> length(unique(dist))
[1] 365` which confirms we have 552 obs with 187 duplicates - as per your method. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm a geographer. You basically learn to sniff out coordinates :-)